# Print output just beside the user input

Tags: c, printf, scanf

According to the question, The user needs to enter the no of hours the vehicle is parked and the total charge for the hours should get printed beside it.

for example:

[image]

I created this simple program

```
#include<stdio.h>>
#include<math.h>

float calculateCharges(float hurs);
int main()
{
    float hours;//total no of hours vehicle is parked
    int i;

    printf("%s%10s%10s", "Car", "Hours", "Charges");
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\t", i);
        scanf("%f", &hours);
        printf("\t%f\n", calculateCharges(hours));
    }




    getch();
    return 0;
}


float calculateCharges(float hurs)
{

    float charges;

    hurs = ceil(hurs);

    if (hurs >= 24) charges = 10; 
    else
    {
        if (hurs <= 3) charges = 2;
        else
        {
            hurs = hurs - 3;
            charges = 2 + 0.5*hurs;

        }

    }

    return charges;
}
```

But now every time I enter hours the charges are getting printed below it instead of beside it. As shown in the image:

[image]

Is there is a way to consume the newline after scanf? So that charges can be printed beside the scanf?

I have modified my code this way too, but it didn't make any difference.

```
printf("%s%10s%10s", "Car", "Hours", "Charges");
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\t", i);
        printf("\t%f\n",(scanf("%f", &hours),calculateCharges(hours)));
    }
```

Let me know if the original question is required. I'm using Visual studio 2017 RC.

Comment: All of those images can be represented as a text. Please [edit] your question and replace all images with text.

Comment: @user694733 I'm unable to give tab between car and hours (and after one space, StackOverflow isn't accepting the other space). As a result, I have kept the first two images as it is.

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly what the question states? I would bet you should read all rows first and then output the entire table. Because once you hit enter, returning to the previous row can only be done through platform-specific invokes. Alternatively, you can use `getc` to parse the input yourself and skip newlines, but it seems unusual for a beginner homework question.

Comment: @Lousy Sir, this is the original question.  (Parking Charges) A parking garage charges a $2.0 minimum fee to park for up to three hours and an additional $0.50 per hour for each hour or part thereof over three hours. The maximum charge for any given 24-hour period is $10. Assume that no car parks for longer than 24 hours at a time.

Comment: Write a program that will calculate and print the parking charges for each of three customers who parked their cars in this garage yesterday. You should enter the hours parked for each customer. Your program should print the results in a neat tabular format. The program should use the function calculateCharges to determine the charge for each customer. Your outputs should appear in the following format: (As shown in the first image)

Comment: @Rishi Shukla: I think you should reset the cursor to the last position before printing the result.

Comment: @RishiShukla Start with one loop to enter the hours parked, then use another look to print the tabulated results. It is not possible in standard C to mix the input and output in the way you are attempting, and I'm quite sure that no introductory course in C would expect students to learn about platform-specific cursor control methods.

Comment: @RishiShukla: there is nothing in this question that says that output should be written as you are typing each input, and such request would be unusual for a console application. Just read all the hours into an array, and then create the table. The accepted answer does what you are asking, but this is not what your professor asked and it's not standard C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf_s always generates a new line upon enter and unfortunately other user input capturing platform independent functions I know of (getc & getchar) do so too. Anyway on Windows it could be done using _getch() from conio header.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getIntFromUser()
{
    char readCharacters[10];

    int index = 0;
    for (int currentChar = _getch(); currentChar != '\r'; currentChar = _getch())
    {
        if (currentChar == EOF)
        {
            // Some error that shouldn't occour in your simple homework program
        }
        if (index > 9)
        {
            // Another possible error case where you would start to write beyond 'readCharacters' array
        }

        // We might as well disallow anything but digits, enter & backspace (You don't need anything else, do you?)
        if ((currentChar < '0' || currentChar > '9') && currentChar != '\b')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (currentChar == '\b')
        {
            if (index > 0)
            {
                // Delete last character
                printf("\b \b");
                readCharacters[index] = '\0';
                --index;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", currentChar);
            readCharacters[index] = currentChar;
            ++index;
        }
    }  

    if (index == 0)
    {
        // User pressed enter without having entered a number, let's give him a zero then
        return 0;
    }

    readCharacters[index] = '\0';

    int retVal = atoi(readCharacters);
    // Worth noting that the value of converted user given string shouldn't be greater than what a signed int can hold

    return retVal;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Unlike scanf_s this will not generate a new line on enter
    printf("getIntFromUser() sample (enter a number)\n");
    int someValue = getIntFromUser();
    printf(" -- This will be printed on the same line. (someValue is %d)\n\n", someValue);


    // scanf_s sample
    int anotherValue;
    printf("scanf_s() sample (Insert a number.)\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &anotherValue);
    printf("This will be printed on a new line\n\n");


    printf("Press any key to exit.");
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT
I feel like the above would become less readable if I were to add a comment over every code line. Instead I'm going to paste some blocks of code 1 by 1.

But first about the _getch function: It waits for the user to type something into the console and then returns the user given char as an int. char implicitly converts to int, so you may compare the _getch result to a character as I did many times in getIntFromUser (e.g. `if (currentChar == '\b') { ... }`).

You should also know about the values a char can hold and what their values are as an int (check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii).
Going by the table the char '0' would be value 48 as an int, which is what _getch would return if the user were to type a 0.

First declare an array/string of 10 elements. Hope you know about them already. In this case the array is basically a chain of 10 elements that are all of type char, which are also referred to as string.

```
char readCharacters[10];
```

An indexer for the string is required.

```
int index = 0;
```

Below we have the usual for loop that...
1st: creates a variable of type int and assigns the result of _getch to it.
2nd: will determine if the loop shall keep executing. In this case the loop will break when currentChar is not '\r', which is an escape sequence that represents enter as a character.
3rd: will execute stuff inside once and then update currentChar with a new _getch.

```
for (int currentChar = _getch(); currentChar != '\r'; currentChar = _getch())
```

Checks if the user input (retrieved via _getch) is smaller than '0' (value 48 as an int) and greater than '9' (value 57 as an int).  If either of them is true it will additionally check if the value of currentChar is not '\b' (value 8 as an int), which is the escape sequence for a backslash.
When that additional check evaluated to true as well then the keyword continue is used. Meaning that the rest of the block in the loop is not executed and instead the loop will start at the top again by getting a new user input and evaluating if the loop is to be continued by checking if obtained currentChar was enter.

```
if ((currentChar < '0' || currentChar > '9') && currentChar != '\b')
{
    continue;
}
```

NOTE: You might want to read the comments on the else statement before you read these.
When the above if statement was false we get to the next if-statement (actually else if) that we see below.
As mentioned above: '\b' is backslash and if this is the user given char as well as string/array index being greater than 0 we move one character backwards in the console by "printing" '\b' and then write an empty character in order to delete what was written at that place previously. That puts us back to the position we were before so we print another backslash.  At this point you might wonder why not just go back to the previous line that scanf_s causes, but that won't work.  We must also not forget to replace the last string character with a null terminator and then set the index back by 1.

```
else if (currentChar == '\b')
{
    if (index > 0)
    {
        // Delete last character
        printf("\b \b");
        readCharacters[index] = '\0';
        --index;
    }
}
```

When we hit this point we know that currentChar is something between 48 and 57 ('0' and '9').
_getch told the program what the user's input was, but we cannot see it in the console unless we print it there. So let's do that.
Also append the user's given character to the string as well as incrementing the index by 1.

```
else
{
    printf("%c", currentChar);
    readCharacters[index] = currentChar;
    ++index;
}
```

Lastly we call the atoi function that will convert our string/array to an integer.

```
int retVal = atoi(readCharacters);
```

Comment: Sir, I would like to mark this one as the correct answer too but sadly I can't choose two correct answers. If you have some time on your hand and can explain `getIntFromUser()` function in some detail (so that any other beginner like me can understand and read it without any doubt ), I would mark this as the correct answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: 'in some detail' has become 'a lot of detail' - hope it doesnt scare you away from reading it

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

//This will set the position of the cursor
void gotoXY(int x, int y) {
    //Initialize the coordinates
    COORD coord = {x, y};
    //Set the position
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
    return;
}

void getCursorXY(int &x, int&y) {
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    if(GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi)) {
        x = csbi.dwCursorPosition.X;
        y = csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y;

    }
}
```

I found it [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/153240-console-cursor-coordinates/).
As already written in one of the answers this solution is **not** platform independent.

But i guess there are similar solutions on other platforms and you can easy set the cursor on the position you want.

Example usage in your main:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    printf("\n%d\t", i);
    scanf("%f", &hours);
    gotoXY( 20, i + 1);
    printf("\t%f\n", calculateCharges(hours));
}
```

---

Workarounds for `scanf` can be found [here](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1352443831&id=1043284392).

Comment: Sir, I'm not quite sure how should I use it. from where should I call these functions? If possible can you edit my code with some explanation and if not that ,give me some hint . Thank you .

Comment: @RishiShukla is this enough?

Comment: Yes ! Thank You !